# How to assign a random number to a variable in ansible?

Tags: ansible

This is an ansible script that I was expecting to print out the same random number three times. Instead, it prints out three random numbers. How do I assign a random number to a variable in ansible so that it is fixed throughout the playbook?

```
---
- name: Test random filter
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    random_number: "{{ 100 | random }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Print the random number
      debug: var=random_number
    - name: Print the random number
      debug: var=random_number
    - name: Print the random number
      debug: var=random_number
```

Comment: note that using a random number means you lose idempotency.

Comment: @tedder42 not always, for example I use this to randomize cron entries and it is still idempotent: `minute: "{{59|random(seed=inventory_hostname)}}"`

Comment: Unless the hostname changes. But there's a slight chance that'll happen.

Answer (score 27):

Just use the `set_fact` module as a task first:

```
 - set_fact:
     r: "{{ 100 | random }}"
   run_once: yes
```

Subsequently, `debug: msg=...` has the value of `r` fixed.

Comment: `run_once: yes` means the number will be same for all hosts for which the playbook will be run. Without it, each host will get own random number which will stay the same through the playbook.

Answer (score 1):

Set facts under task:

```
---
- name: Test random filter
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: set fact here
      set_fact:
        randome_number: "{{ 100 | random }}"
      run_once: yes
    - name: Print the random number
      debug: var=random_number
    - name: Print the random number
      debug: var=random_number
    - name: Print the random number
      debug: var=random_number
```